# Add input submit after href

Tags: html, button, input, submit, href

Im trying to add the input number just after the churchid= when click the submit button. I can't combine the input with the href. This is the code that I have, where redirect me to the href but doesn't add the input after =

```
  <body> 
    <label for="number">Number:</label><br>
     <input type="text" id="number"><br><br>
     
     <a href="https://afiliaciones.ajecpr.com/api/unsubmit?fiscalYear=2023&churchId=">
    
      <button>Unlock</button>
    </a>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<form></form>` and `<input type="hidden">` in HTML.

```html
<body>
  <form action="https://afiliaciones.ajecpr.com/api/unsubmit">
    <input type="hidden" name="fiscalYear" value="2023">
    <label for="number">Number:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="churchId"><br><br>

    <button type="submit">Unlock</button>
  </form>
</body>
```